# GBQ Convert Data types en Mass

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery, type-conversion

I have a table wth many columns and various numerical data types. I am trying to figure out a way to convert all these data types to the same numeric type without listing each one idivudally and doing

`SELECT CAST(column1 as Numeric), CAST(column2 as Numeric), ect...`

SAMPLE DATA

[image]

In this example, Group would stay the same and Apple, Bananas and Orange would all be converted to the same data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
execute immediate (select '''
select `Group`, ''' || (select string_agg('cast(' || Fruit || ' as Numeric) as ' || Fruit ) from (
select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":') Fruits
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1), unnest(Fruits) Fruit)  ||   
''' from `project.dataset.table`''');
```

if applied to sample data in your question (note I changed Numeric to Float64 in above script to produce below so result of casting is more visible) - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail this is great, to save this output to a table where would that statement got. CREATE or REPLACE at the begining does not seem to work

Comment: doable. try to get it work by yourself first! if still the problem  - ask/post more questions. but please - first try by yourself - believe me it is easy! Meantime, if purpose of saving into table is just for than to use in next query or script - this might be possible to avoid doing this and rather combine all in one script - obviously it is much more complex , so it might be easier to do your way and create intermediate table