# GBQ Execute Immediate Save Results to Table

Tags: google-bigquery, procedure, create-table, execute-immediate

Hi All I am trying to same the results from this query into a table on GBQ. I have linked the previous question for reference

[GBQ Convert Data types en Mass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68203858/gbq-convert-data-types-en-mass/68204028?noredirect=1#comment120541854_68204028)

Starting Code

```
execute immediate (select '''
select `Group`, ''' || (select string_agg('cast(' || Fruit || ' as Numeric) as ' || Fruit ) from (
select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":') Fruits
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1), unnest(Fruits) Fruit)  ||   
''' from `project.dataset.table`''');
```

Various Attempts

```
Create or Replace Table1 as
execute immediate (select '''
select `Group`, ''' || (select string_agg('cast(' || Fruit || ' as Numeric) as ' || Fruit ) from (
select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":') Fruits
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1), unnest(Fruits) Fruit)  ||   
''' from `project.dataset.table`''');
```

---

```
execute immediate (select '''
select `Group`, ''' || (select string_agg('cast(' || Fruit || ' as Numeric) as ' || Fruit ) 
INTO Table1
from (
select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":') Fruits
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1), unnest(Fruits) Fruit)  ||   
''' from `project.dataset.table`''');
```

---

```
execute immediate (select '''
select `Group`, ''' || (select string_agg('cast(' || Fruit || ' as Numeric) as ' || Fruit ) from (
select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":') Fruits
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1), unnest(Fruits) Fruit)  ||   
''' from `project.dataset.table`''') INTO Table1;
```

---

```
execute immediate (select '''
select `Group`, ''' || (select string_agg('cast(' || Fruit || ' as Numeric) as ' || Fruit ) from (
select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":') Fruits
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1), unnest(Fruits) Fruit)  ||   
''' from `project.dataset.table`''' INTO Table1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
execute immediate (select '''create or replace table `project.dataset.table2` as 
select `Group`, ''' || (select string_agg('cast(' || Fruit || ' as float64) as ' || Fruit ) from (
select regexp_extract_all(to_json_string((select as struct * except(`Group`) from unnest([t]))), r'"([^"]+)":') Fruits
from `project.dataset.table` t limit 1), unnest(Fruits) Fruit)  ||   
''' from `project.dataset.table`''');
```

Comment: code works beautifully, thank you from 2022!!!